# Is there is another way to Sync Between Computers?

Tags: sync

I try so many time for more than 1hr to create and account in **Ubuntu One** to use only the feature **Sync Between Computers** but is impossible to read the security code and always get the error `Wrong Captcha Solution`. Is there is another solution to sync apps between computers beside **Ubuntu One**? even if I have to pay for it. Is so impossible to create and simple account.

Comment: Ubuntu1 is almost dead. There are many other things you can try. Do you want a readymade GUI app or are you ready to do some commandline work(you will have to just do it once anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure how you missed it but the entire front page of the Ubuntu One website is a huge notice that says, " **The service has been discontinued** / We are sorry to notify you that the Ubuntu One file services have been shut down."

July 31 is the FINAL FINAL chance to remove your data from it before it gets wiped.

It looks like they've hidden the sign up form but not removed it completely.  Interestingly the captcha works fine for me and I was able to sign up.  But since it's all going to be wiped on July 31, it's not worth signing up.

Answer (score 0):

There are various alternatives like [google drive](https://drive.google.com/), [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [owncloud](http://owncloud.org/).
They all have ubuntu clients and offer free space.